# Анимация лого WINTER BASH

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Заканчивается сезон  WINTER BASH **2020**
Хотелось бы, как-то отметить это событие.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображении цифрами отмечены, желаемые объекты для анимации

**Сценарий анимации:**

1. Генератор шляп.
   Должен неравномерно перемещаться вверх-вниз
2. Знак вопроса должен плавать в пространстве с одновременным изменением в размерах.
   Что символизирует сбор информации о раскрытии условий получения "секретных шляп"
3. Воздушный шарик должен равномерно покачиваться.
4. Шляпа должна перемещаться вдоль траектории слова WINTER
5. Покачивание луны. Должно начаться после выполнения пункта 4 сценария
6. Большая синяя шляпа совершает поступательные движения в поисках новых шляп.
   Через некоторое время после начала выполнения п.6, сверху должны начать падать шляпы.
7. Анимация звёзд, должна начаться после нахождения всех шляп.

Как реализовать данный сценарий анимации?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T)

Код получился довольно большой, чтобы разместить его в снипете при ограничении 30.000 символов, пришлось его довольно сильно оптимизировать и избавиться от некоторых украшательств.
Комментарии остались по основным моментам работы программы, надеюсь что они помогут.
Видимо придется делать дополнительный ответ, чтобы раскрыть некоторые интересные подробности реализации пунктов сценария.

Запуск анимации начнется после нажатия на кнопку `Start`

Использован музыкальный трек: **[Candy Dulfer](https://candydulfer.nl/biography/) / [Dave Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Stewart_(musician_and_producer)) - [Lily Was Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5kKo2_2MzI)**

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#000;
}
#hat {
stroke:#000;
fill:#30BAE4;
}
#Stroke_bottom {
fill:#8DEBB5;
stroke:#971B59;
stroke-width:4;
stroke-dashoffset:350;
stroke-dasharray:350;
fill-opacity:0;
filter:url(#dropShadow);
}

#q {
fill:#8DEBB5;
stroke:#971B59;
stroke-width:4;
stroke-dashoffset:1366;
stroke-dasharray:1366;
fill-opacity:0;
filter:url(#dropShadow);
}
#cloud {
fill:#FFFCFF;
stroke:#971B59;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dashoffset:1649;
stroke-dasharray:1649;
filter:url(#dropShadow);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 2787 768">



<defs>
 <path id="trace" stroke="none" d="m1115 163 46 98 25-52 26 53 46-97 25 1v97h33l1-97 81 99v-99l57 1 1 98 3-1-1-98h37 22v98l61 1 1-3-58-2v-46l55 1v-5h-54v-41l79-4v99h4l-1-40 27-1 22 41 4-1-21-40c0 0 10-4 14-8 4-3 7-7 9-12 2-6 3-13 1-19-2-6-6-10-11-14-4-3-9-4-14-5-10-2-31-1-31-1" />
 <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="16" result="shadow"/>
       <feComposite in2="mask" in="shadow" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge> 
    </filter>  
    
    <filter id="shadow" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feOffset result="offsetResult" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2" />
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurResult" in="offsetResult" stdDeviation="4" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurResult" mode="normal" />
    </filter>  
    
    <filter id="flood" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.15" > 
            <!-- Анемация затемнения фона -->
            <animate id="back" attributeName="flood-opacity" begin="btn1.click+32s" dur="20s" values="0.15;0.8;0.8;0.15;0.15" additive="sum" fill="freeze"    repeatcount="indefinite" />
        </feFlood>
        <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="atop" result="comp"/> 
         
    </filter>  
    <mask id="msk" >
        <!-- Звезды  --> 
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"  />   
        <path d="m280 446c0 0-1 7-3 11-1 3-3 6-6 8-3 2-6 3-9 4-2 1-6 3-6 3 0 0 4 1 6 2 3 1 5 1 8 3 2 2 4 4 6 6 1 2 2 5 3 7 1 2 2 7 2 7 0 0 1-5 2-8 1-3 2-6 4-8 2-2 5-4 7-5 4-2 14-4 14-4 0 0-5-1-8-2-3-1-5-2-8-4-3-2-5-5-6-8-2-4-2-5-4-12zM166 315" />
  
  <path d="m166 315c0 0-1 5-3 8-1 2-2 5-4 6-3 2-10 4-10 4 0 0 5 1 8 3 2 1 4 2 5 4 1 2 3 3 3 5 1 2 1 5 1 5 0 0 1-5 2-7 1-2 2-3 3-4 1-1 3-2 5-3 2-1 7-2 7-2 0 0-3-1-5-2-2-1-4-1-6-3-2-2-3-4-4-6-1-2-3-7-3-7z" />
  
  <path d="m1715 288c-2 5-3 9-5 12-2 4-5 7-8 10-3 2-7 3-11 4-3 1-8 2-8 2 0 0 6 1 9 2 4 1 8 2 11 5 3 2 6 6 8 9 3 5 5 15 5 15 0 0 2-11 5-15 2-3 5-6 8-8 3-2 7-3 11-5 2-1 7-2 7-2 0 0-5-2-8-3-3-1-6-1-9-3-3-2-6-5-8-8-3-4-3-9-6-14z" />
  <path d="m1557 61c0 0-1 4-2 6-1 2-2 3-3 4-2 2-4 2-6 3-1 1-4 1-4 1 0 0 4 2 6 3 2 1 3 2 5 4 1 2 2 3 3 5 1 1 2 4 2 4 0 0 1-4 2-5 1-2 2-3 4-5 2-1 4-2 5-3 1-1 4-2 4-2 0 0-3-1-5-2-2-1-4-2-5-4-1-1-2-3-3-5-1-1-2-4-2-4z" />
  <path d="m2380 375c0 0-2 7-3 10-1 4-3 7-5 10-2 3-6 4-9 6-3 2-10 3-10 3 0 0 6 2 9 3 4 2 8 3 11 6 3 3 4 8 6 12 1 3 2 8 2 8 0 0 2-6 3-9 1-3 3-7 5-10 2-3 5-5 9-6 4-2 12-4 12-4 0 0-6-2-8-3-2-1-5-2-7-3-2-1-4-3-6-6-2-2-2-5-3-7-1-3-4-10-4-10z" />
  <path d="m2473 233c0 0-1 4-3 6-1 2-2 3-4 5-2 2-3 3-5 4-1 1-4 1-4 1 0 0 4 2 6 3 2 1 4 2 5 4 1 2 2 4 3 6 1 2 2 5 2 5 0 0 1-4 2-6 1-2 2-4 3-5 1-1 3-2 4-3 2-1 7-3 7-3 0 0-5-2-8-3-2-1-3-2-4-4-1-1-1-3-2-5 0-1-1-3-1-3z" />
  <path d="m2269 59c0 0-2 1-3 2-2 1-3 3-5 4-2 1-5 1-7 1-2 0-6 0-6 0 0 0 3 3 5 5 1 2 2 3 2 5 1 3 0 5 0 8 0 1 0 3 0 3 0 0 4-3 6-5 1-1 3-2 4-2 2 0 4 0 6 0 2 0 6 1 6 1 0 0-3-3-4-4-1-2-3-3-4-6-1-2 0-4 0-6 0-2 1-5 1-5z" />
  <path d="m1477 596c0 0-1 3-2 5-1 2-2 4-3 5-2 2-5 3-8 5-1 1-4 1-4 1 0 0 4 1 5 1 2 1 4 2 6 3 2 2 3 4 4 7 1 2 2 5 2 5 0 0 1-4 2-6 1-2 2-3 4-5 1-1 3-2 5-3 2-1 5-2 5-2 0 0-3-2-5-3-2-1-3-2-5-3-2-2-3-4-4-6-1-1-2-4-2-4z" />
   <path  d="m830 136c0 0-1 8-2 11-1 2-2 4-4 5-1 1-3 2-4 3-2 1-6 2-6 2 0 0 4 2 6 3 2 1 4 2 5 4 1 1 2 3 3 5 1 2 2 6 2 6 0 0 1-5 2-7 1-1 2-3 3-4 2-1 4-2 5-3 2-1 6-3 6-3 0 0-4-1-6-2-2-1-3-2-4-3-1-1-2-3-3-4-1-3-2-11-2-11" />    
        </mask>
     <radialGradient id="grad_bl" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="30%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="20%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#31BCE5" offset="90%"/>
 </radialGradient>   
</defs>   
    <!-- Нижний фон -->
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow" />
  <!-- Анимация мерцания звезд через маску -->
  <animate id="back" attributeName="fill" begin="btn1.click+32s" dur="3s" values="red;yellow;cyan" fill="freeze" additive="sum"   repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAr3.jpg" mask="url(#msk)" filter="url(#flood)"  height="100%" width="100%"/>    
                     
   <!-- Луна -->
 <g id="moon" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" filter="url(#shadow)" transform="rotate(30,1750,10.4)">
  <path fill="#8BECBD" d="m1729 45 28-35 36 31-28 33zM1717 37l58 48-5 8-57-49M1717 37l58 48-5 8-57-49" />
  <path fill="#8BECBD" d="m1717 37 58 48-5 8-57-49z" />
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1724 54c0 0-11 15-15 23-4 9-7 19-8 30-1 10 0 21 3 31 2 9 6 18 11 25 5 7 10 13 17 18 8 6 16 11 25 15 11 4 23 6 34 5 9 0 19-3 27-6 5-2 11-4 15-7 6-4 11-8 16-13 2-2 5-7 5-7l-15 3-17 0-20-5-14-7-14-13-10-15-3-6c0 0 3-1 4-1 1-1 2-2 3-3 1-2 1-4 0-6 0-1-2-1-2-2-1-1-3-2-4-4-1-1-2-2-3-4-1-2-2-4-3-6 0-4 2-13 2-13z" />
  <path d="m1746 128c0 0 6 6 9 7 4 1 12 0 12 0" />
  <path d="m1745 96c2 0 4 1 4 2 1 1 1 3 0 4-1 1-2 2-3 2-1 0-3-1-4-2-1-1-1-2 0-4 1-1 2-2 3-2z" /> 
         <!-- Анимация луны  an_hat.end-->
    <animateTransform id="an_Moon" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="an_hat.end" dur="6s" values="30,1750,10.4;
                10,1750,10.4;
                20,1750,10.4; 
                -30,1750,10.4;
                0,1750,10.4;
                30,1750,10.4"
                keyTimes="0;0.15;0.25;0.45;0.85;1"
                repeatCount="indefinite" 
                    />   
                    
  </g>  
    <!-- Крайняя справа шляпа -->
 <g  stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" filter="url(#shadow)" >
 <path fill="#971B59" d="m2648 190c0 0 35 19 52 30 22 14 63 45 63 45l-37 61-22 36-49-35-34-20-34-19zM2588 287l68 40 49 36-13 20-115-74" />
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m2588 287 68 40 49 36-13 20-115-74z" />
  <path fill="#31BCE5" d="m2537 290c1-1 3-1 4 0 8 4 15 7 22 11 9 5 18 11 27 16 15 9 29 18 44 27 20 13 39 26 58 39 5 4 11 7 16 11 5 3 9 6 14 10 1 1 4 2 4 4 0 3-1 7-4 7-2 1-3-1-4-2-5-3-10-8-15-12-12-9-25-17-37-26-15-10-46-27-46-29 0-1-27-18-41-27-9-5-18-10-27-16-4-2-8-4-11-6-2-1-4-2-4-5 0-2 2-3 3-4z"/>
  <path fill="#911A5B" d="m2533 294-2 4 12 11 18 13 26 18 20 14 21 13 19 12 27 17 17 9 10 6 10 5 8-1-9-6-10-8-15-11-13-9-32-21-27-15-33-22-9-5-15-8-14-8z" /> 
      <!-- Анимация крайней справа шляпы -->
    <animateTransform id="Hat_right" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="btn1.click;Hat_right.end+2s" dur="1.0s" values="0,0;-60,180;0,0" repeatCount="2" keyTimes="0;0.7;1" />  
  </g>  
                   <!-- воздушный шарик  -->
 <g id="AirBall" transform="rotate(-15 536 395.8)">
 <path fill="url(#grad_bl)" stroke="#2A9EC1" stroke-width="4" filter="url(#dropShadow)" d="m360 167c11-8 24-13 37-13 13 0 27 4 38 11 13 8 24 20 30 34 8 16 7 34 9 52 1 13 2 27 1 40 0 6 2 13-2 16-3 3-8 1-13 1-8 0-17-1-25-3-11-2-22-4-33-8-11-3-23-6-32-12-9-5-17-13-23-21-6-9-12-20-13-31-2-12-1-25 4-36 5-11 13-22 24-29z" />
                <!-- Хвостик шарика -->
 <path fill="#FFFBFF" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="4" d="m474 305c2-1 4 0 6 0 2 0 5 0 7 2 1 1 1 3 1 4 0 1 0 3-1 3-1 1-4-1-4 1-1 1 1 3 0 4 0 1-1 3-2 3-2 1-3-3-5-2-1 1 0 3-1 4-1 1-2 2-3 2-2 0-4-2-4-4-1-2 0-5 0-8 0-1 0-3 1-4 1-2 4-3 6-4z" /> 
  
             <!-- Веревка шарика -->
  <path fill="none" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="4"  d="m 536.08463,395.61831 c 0,0 -12.58625,-24.39313 -19.91851,-35.97377 -4.23232,-6.68457 -8.89916,-13.10432 -13.85276,-19.27342 -3.20473,-3.9911 -6.65792,-7.7864 -10.239,-11.44359 -2.88203,-2.94329 -9.03442,-8.43212 -9.03442,-8.43212" />
             <!-- Анимация воздушного шарика -->
     <animateTransform id="an_AirBall" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="an_hat.end;an_AirBall.end+12s" dur="5s"  
        values="-15 536 395.8;40 536 395.8;60 536 395.8;-15 536 395.8" fill="freeze"  repeatCount="5" />  
  </g>
                
          <!-- Знак вопроса -->
  <path id="q"  d="m560 343c-5-16-3-35 2-51 4-16 14-30 24-42 10-12 23-22 37-30 14-8 30-13 45-16 17-3 35-4 53-2 19 2 38 5 55 12 18 8 35 18 48 33 15 17 27 37 32 58 6 27 4 55-4 81-6 18-18 33-30 48-10 12-25 21-36 32-11 11-25 21-33 35-4 7-6 16-8 24-2 9 0 20-5 28-5 9-13 17-23 21-10 4-22 4-32 1-9-3-17-9-23-17-5-8-7-18-8-28-1-14 0-29 4-43 3-11 8-21 14-30 6-9 14-16 21-23 10-10 22-19 32-28 10-9 23-17 30-29 5-7 8-15 9-23 2-10 2-20-2-29-3-9-9-19-17-25-9-7-21-10-32-11-11-1-22 1-32 5-8 4-17 9-22 16-5 6-5 15-7 22-2 7-4 15-8 22-4 6-8 13-15 16-8 4-19 4-28 4-8-1-17-2-24-7-7-5-12-12-14-20z" >
     <animate id="q_Stroke" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="btn1.click;q_scale.end+4s" dur="4s" values="1366;0" fill="freeze" /> 
       <animate id="q_Fill" attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="q_Stroke.end" dur="4s" values="0;0.5;1" fill="freeze" /> 
        <animateTransform id="q_move" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="q_Fill.end" dur="8s" values="0 0;0 -100;-200 -100;0 0" repeatCount="1" additive="sum"  />  
           <animateTransform id="q_scale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="q_Fill.end" dur="8s" values="1,;0.75;0.75;1;1" repeatCount="1" additive="sum"  />   
  </path>
                  <!-- Хвостик знака вопроса -->
  <path fill="#8DEBB5" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" d="m696 575c-3 1-5 3-7 5-1 1-2 2-2 3 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 3 0 4 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 1 3 0 1 0 1-1 2-2 0 0 0-1 1-1 1 0 2 2 3 2 1 0 3-1 4-2 1-1 0-3 0-4-1-2-2-3-4-4-1-1-2-2-3-2-1-1-3-1-4-1z" />
                   <!-- Нижний шарик вопроса -->
<path id="Stroke_bottom"   d="m691 709c0 2-3 3-4 4-1 1-2 2-3 4-1 1-1 2-1 4 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 3-2 4-1 1 0 1 2 2 3 1 0 2 0 3 0 1-1 1-2 2-3 1 0 3 2 4 1 1 0 2-2 2-3 0-2-2-3-3-5-1-1-2-2-3-3-1-1-3-1-3-2 0-4 6-6 9-9 3-3 6-6 9-9 4-5 9-9 13-14 3-4 6-8 8-13 2-5 4-11 3-16 0-6-2-11-4-17-2-5-4-9-8-13-4-4-9-7-14-10-4-2-9-3-14-4-3 0-7 0-10 0-5 1-10 2-14 3-4 2-9 5-12 8-5 5-9 10-11 17-2 7-3 14-2 21 1 5 3 9 5 13 2 4 5 8 8 12 3 4 6 7 9 11 3 4 7 7 10 10 2 2 4 3 6 5 2 2 5 2 5 5z" >
     <animate id="an_Stroke_bottom" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="btn1.click+1s;q_scale.end+4s" dur="4s" values="350;0" fill="freeze" /> 
       <animate id="q_Fill" attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="q_Stroke.end" dur="4s" values="0;0.5;1" fill="freeze" />       

       <animateTransform id="Stroke_bottom_move" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="q_Fill.end" dur="8s" values="0 0;0 -100;-200 -100;0 0" repeatCount="1" additive="sum"  />  
           <animateTransform id="Stroke_bottom_scale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="q_Fill.end" dur="8s" values="1,;0.75;0.75;1;1" repeatCount="1" additive="sum"  />   
    </path> 


<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
 <g id="hat" transform="translate(-1320,-180)" filter="url(#shadow)" >
  <path d="m1299 184 47-17 3 6-47 17zM1309 181l-10-29 29-10 10 29M1309 181l-10-29 29-10 10 29" />
  <path d="m1309 181-10-29 29-10 10 29z" />
   </g>
    <!-- Анимация шляпы вдоль пути winter   -->
  <animateMotion id="an_hat" xlink:href="#hat" begin="an_BigHat.end+0.5s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
  </animateMotion>
 
  
    <!--  Шляпа на синих прямоугольниках   --> 
 <g id="winterHat"  stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"  >
 <path fill="#2FBAE5" d="M938.7 261.2H1063.9V631.7H938.7Z" />
  <path  d="M957.4 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M976.1 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M993.2 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1009.4 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1025.5 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1045.1 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1063.9 261.2V631.7" />
  
      
  <path id="brimHat" fill="#FCB660" d="M939 194 928 194c0 0-13 0-19 4-4 2-7 6-9 10-2 4-1 9-1 14 0 5 1 10 3 14 2 5 5 9 8 12 4 5 8 10 14 13 6 4 14 7 21 9 7 2 14 4 21 5 6 1 12 1 18 2 6 1 12 1 18 2 5 0 10 0 15-1 6 0 11-1 17-2 7-1 13-3 20-4 8-2 17-4 24-9 6-4 12-8 17-14 5-5 8-11 11-18 2-5 4-11 3-17-1-6-5-11-10-15-4-2-13-3-13-3l-13-1z" />
  <path id="brimHat2" fill="#971B59" d="m924 194c0 0-5 7-7 11-1 3-1 7 0 10 1 4 2 9 5 12 2 4 5 7 8 10 4 4 8 8 13 10 6 4 13 6 20 8 7 2 14 3 21 4 5 1 10 1 15 1 6 0 12 0 17-1 7 0 13-1 20-2 6-1 13-2 19-5 7-3 13-6 18-11 6-5 12-12 15-19 2-6 3-12 1-18-1-4-7-9-7-9z" /> 
  <path id="topHat" fill="#FCB660" d="m939 218c0 0-1-25-2-37-1-22-2-43-4-65 0-4-2-10 6-10 40 0 84-2 126 1 4 0 11 0 12 3 1 3 0 8 0 8l-4 54-3 47z" /> 
  <path id="bottomHat" fill="#FEFBFE"  d="m939 221 129 0 0 17c0 0-39 6-58 6-23 0-68-5-68-5z" />
          <!-- Анимация шляпы на синих прямоугольниках   -->
  
  <animateTransform id="an_BigHat"  attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="btn1.click" dur="5s" values="0,0;0,250;0,0;0,250;0,0;0,400;0,100;0,500;0,0" repeatCount="1" />
  </g> 
  
  <path id="cloud" transform="translate(0 -4)" d="m843 766c-14 0-27-12-35-24-7-11-10-27-6-39 4-11 25-24 25-24 0 0 15-5 23-4 10 1 18 6 27 12 5 4 16 1 17-3 5-12 7-23 13-33 6-10 12-20 22-27 10-7 23-9 35-11 7-1 14-3 22-2 8 0 16 1 24 4 7 3 12 10 19 11 6 1 17-2 17-2 0 0 6-19 11-28 10-16 22-31 37-41 16-10 34-16 53-17 15-1 30 3 43 8 16 6 31 15 43 27 6 6 9 14 14 22 2 3 7-1 10 0 4 1 8 6 11 4 10-4 18-9 27-11 8-2 17-3 26-2 12 1 23 3 34 8 11 5 21 12 30 21 9 10 16 23 21 36 2 7 2 15 3 22 0 7-2 14 0 20 1 2 3 4 5 5 3 2 6 8 9 6 6-5 14-8 21-9 8-1 17-1 23 3 10 7 16 21 16 33 0 9-3 18-9 25-5 5-20 9-20 9 0 0-408 8-610 3z" >
      <animate id="an_cloud" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="btn1.click+85s;an_cloud.end+5s" dur="8s" values="1649;0;0;1649" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
            
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<g id="Hat+Legs" >
 <g id="LegL" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2">
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1721 765 5-66 46 0-12 28c0 0-1 8 0 12 1 3 3 6 6 8 2 2 5 3 8 3 2 1 4 0 5 1 2 1 3 3 4 5 0 1 0 3-1 4-1 1-2 3-4 3-19 1-58 0-58 0zM1734 698l1-11" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1734 698 1-11v-13l-1-8c0 0-1-20-3-30-1-5-4-16-4-16l33-13 5 10 5 10c0 0 3 10 5 14 1 4 3 7 4 11 0 4-1 11-1 11l-3 13-4 11-4 10z" />
     <!-- Анимация левой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="LeftForward" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="RightBack.end" dur="0.5s" 
      values="0 1731 607;-28 1731 607;0 1731 607" fill="freeze" /> 
     
  </g> 
  
   <g id="LegR" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(28 1817 587)">
  <path fill="#FEFAFE" d="m1886 682 38 54c0 0 33-18 48-30 1-1 3-2 3-3 1-1 1-3 0-5-1-2-2-3-4-4-2-1-4 0-6 0-2 0-4 2-5 2-2 0-3 0-5 0-3 0-6 0-9-2-3-2-4-7-6-10-5-8-15-25-15-25zM1915 663" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1915 663c0 0-8-14-13-21-4-5-8-11-13-16-2-2-5-4-8-6-3-3-6-5-9-8-8-6-15-15-24-19-9-3-22-9-29-2-3 3-1 9 0 14 1 5 5 10 8 15 2 3 5 7 8 10 4 4 9 6 13 9 5 4 8 8 13 12 6 5 12 9 18 15 3 3 8 9 8 9l4 7z" />
     <!-- Анимация правой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="RightBack" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="an_hat.end;LeftForward.end" dur="0.5s" 
      values="28 1817 587;0 1817 587;28 1817 587" fill="freeze" /> 
      
  </g>
    <g id="Hand" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"> 
  <path id=HandR fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1861 533c4-1 7 3 11 4 3 1 5 1 8 2 4 1 9 2 13 2 4 0 8 1 12 0 4 0 7-2 11-2 3 0 5-1 8-1 2 0 3-1 5-1 1 0 2-1 3-1 1 0 2 2 3 3 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2-1 3-2 2-5 3-7 4-3 1-7 2-10 3-3 1-6 2-9 3-3 1-6 1-9 1-3 0-6 0-9 0-5 0-11-1-16-2-3-1-6-2-9-4-2-1-4-2-5-3-1-2-2-4-2-7 0-2 2-5 4-5zM1678 585" />
  <path id=HandL fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1678 585c-2 0-5 2-7 3-3 1-6 3-8 5-3 2-5 4-7 7-3 3-5 6-8 10-2 2-3 4-4 6-2 3-2 6-4 9-1 3-2 5-3 8-1 3-1 5-1 8-1 3-2 6-2 9 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 3 1 0 2-2 3-3 1-2 2-5 2-7 1-3 2-6 3-10 2-4 3-8 5-11 2-3 4-5 6-7 2-3 4-6 7-8 2-2 5-3 7-4 2-1 5-2 7-4 2-1 4-2 5-4 1-2 3-5 2-7-1-3-5-5-8-5z" /> 
  

 <path id="BigHat" fill="#FDB761" d="m1628 513c0 0-45-16-69-24-2-1-4-3-4-5 4-13 7-25 12-36 4-9 8-18 13-27 1-2 4-3 6-2 24 8 69 25 69 25 0 0-10 22-14 33-4 12-12 37-12 37zM1622 540l4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12" />
  <path fill="#FDB761" d="m1622 540 4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12c0 0 2-7 5-9 1-1 2 0 3 0 2 0 6 2 6 2l2 1-7 8-8 18-10 24-8 20-7 19c0 0-4 11-5 16-1 5 0 7-1 16 0 3-8-1-8-1z" />

 <path id="AngleHat" fill="#991458" d="m1641 530-8 13c0 0-1-1-2-1-2-4 0-10 1-14 1-5 4-15 4-15z" /> 
 
  <path id="AngleHat2" fill="#991458" d="m1663 442 4-10 2-4 7-8c0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 5 0 5l-1 7-7 4z" />
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1694 664-58-151c0 0 16-46 25-66 6-14 28-16 77-36 61-25 75-26 75-26l81 200c0 0-61 22-91 34-36 15-108 46-108 46z" /> 
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1634.1 695.2 55.2-28.6 94.7-41.3 126.2-45.7 41.6-12.2c0 0 4.7-2.4 6-0.9 3.7 4.7 7.1 11 4.3 12.4-5.3 2.5-20.4 5.7-20.4 5.7l-32 9.6-97.1 36-133.4 56.1c0 0-18.8 8.4-27.5 14-4.2 2.7-8.5 5.7-11.7 9.4-2.7 3.2-6-14.5-6-14.5z" />
  <path fill="#921D57" d="m1962.3 579.8 0.9 3.3-11.1 8.4-30.1 13.6-31.6 13.9-52.4 22-56.6 22.9-50.9 19.9-25.9 8.7-27.4 9.3-20.5 6.9c0 0-12.3 5.8-17.2 2.7-4.6-3 12.3-10.8 12.3-10.8l23.2-11.7 59.6-24.7 44.3-18.7 55.7-23.8 37.9-12.3 34.6-12.9 26.5-8.7 18.1-4.5 6.6-1.8z" />  
      
  </g>   
       <!-- Анимация горизонтального движения шляпы -->
       <animateTransform id="an_Horiz" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="an_hat.end+5s;an_Horiz.end+2s" dur="20s"   
        values="0, 0;600 0;600,-350;0,0" fill="freeze" additive="sum" repeatCount="1" />   
        <g>
     <!-- глаза + рот большой шляпы eyes + mouth of a big hat -->
  <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="m1831.7 535.5c0 0 10.1 14.4 16.8 9.9 5.9-4 4.4-17.1 4.4-17.1" />
  <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.1 509.1c1.1-0.6 2.6 0.1 3.5 0.9 1.7 1.5 2.5 3.9 2.6 6.1 0.1 1.3 0.1 3.1-1.1 3.7-1.2 0.7-3.1-0.3-4-1.3-1.6-1.6-1.9-4.2-1.9-6.4 0-1.1-0.1-2.6 0.9-3.1zM1824.7 510.4" />
  <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.7 510.4c0.5-0.3 1.2 0.3 1.7 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.9 1.1 1.2 1.7 0.4 0.8 0.7 1.6 1 2.5 0.1 0.5 0.3 1 0.2 1.5-0.1 0.7 0 1.7-0.6 2-0.7 0.3-1.5-0.4-2-0.9-0.6-0.6-0.8-1.4-1.1-2.2-0.4-1.1-0.6-2.3-0.7-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.5 0.2-1.8z" />
  <g transform="translate(18.821694,-6.6252361)">
    <path  stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.1 509.1c1.1-0.6 2.6 0.1 3.5 0.9 1.7 1.5 2.5 3.9 2.6 6.1 0.1 1.3 0.1 3.1-1.1 3.7-1.2 0.7-3.1-0.3-4-1.3-1.6-1.6-1.9-4.2-1.9-6.4 0-1.1-0.1-2.6 0.9-3.1zM1824.7 510.4" />
    <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.7 510.4c0.5-0.3 1.2 0.3 1.7 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.9 1.1 1.2 1.7 0.4 0.8 0.7 1.6 1 2.5 0.1 0.5 0.3 1 0.2 1.5-0.1 0.7 0 1.7-0.6 2-0.7 0.3-1.5-0.4-2-0.9-0.6-0.6-0.8-1.4-1.1-2.2-0.4-1.1-0.6-2.3-0.7-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.5 0.2-1.8z" />
   <!--  Анимация глаз + рта вверх-вниз -->
   </g>  
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="an_hat.end+5s" dur="1s"  
        values="0 0;0 -20;-5 -20;0 0" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="indefinite" />  
    </g>
    </g>   
    
         
    <!-- Шляпы --> 
     <g>
     <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="GimmeSpace" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CE3b.png"  width="206px" height="218px"> 
       <animateTransform id="an_Gimme" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="34s;an_Gimme.end+50s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-400 800" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>     
     <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Carnaval" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Khg.png"  width="206px" height="218px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="24s;Carnaval.end+5s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-250 800" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>      
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="ThisIsFine" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFTT7.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="40s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;50 780" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>    
<g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Samovar" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1O31.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="50s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;-100 780" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g>  
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Balalaika" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC5za.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="53s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;-800 680" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>        
<g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Milliner" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztauc.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="56s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;640 390" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g>      
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Kitsune" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q507j.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="60s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;640 390;-150 680" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>    
<g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="SocialDistancing" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4XGr.png"  width="150px" height="150px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="64s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;-271 285" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g> 
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Matryoshka" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mtVe.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="67s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;640 390;-450 570" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>
<g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="WarmWelcome" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE0tq.png"  width="150px" height="150px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="70s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;-1085 700" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g> 
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Vexillologist" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVOzH.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="73s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;640 390;-150 470" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" /> 
            
     </image> 
    </g> 
<g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="World" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2xFc.png"  width="150px" height="150px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="76s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;315 760" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g> 
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Movin" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/G51nw.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="78s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;640 390;420 777" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>
<g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Bouncer" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhnHn.png"  width="150px" height="150px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="80s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;-580 850" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g>  
         
  <g id="btn1" fill-opacity="1"  transform="translate(-700,-200)" filter="url(#dropShadow)" onclick='play()' >
     <circle  cx="870" cy="255" r="16" fill="#30BBE4"  /> 
     <text id="txt1" x="750" y="270" font-size="3rem" fill="white" >Start</text>
    <animate  attributeName="fill-opacity" begin="btn1.click" dur="1s" values="1;0" fill="freeze"    repeatcount="1" /> 
 </g> 
 
</svg>
<script>

var zodiac = new Audio();
zodiac.src = src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Kendi Dalfer–Meeting.mp3";

function play() {
  zodiac.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: O_o вот это блокбастер))

Comment: я вообще люблю именно эту композицию - но ответ этот не видел

Answer (score 8):

### Пояснение работы элементов анимации

**#1.Покачивание луны**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для равномерного покачивания луны необходимо найти точные координаты верхнего уголка зеленой шляпы, чтобы подставить их в команду анимации вращения

```
let bb = moon.getBBox();
console.log( bb.x + bb.width / 2 ); // координата X  
console.log(bb.y); // координата Y
```

Получилось `x="1753"` и `y="10"`

```
<animateTransform id="an_Moon" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s" values="30,1753,10.4;
                    10,1753,10.4;
                    20,1753,10.4; 
                    -30,1753,10.4;
                    0,1753,10.4;
                    30,1753,10.4"
                    keyTimes="0;0.15;0.25;0.45;0.85;1"
                    repeatCount="indefinite" 
                  />
```

Атрибут `keyTimes="0;0.15;0.25;0.45;0.85;1"` задает неравномерную скорость вращения луны.

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.s0{
    fill:none;
    stroke:#000;
}
#hat {
stroke:#000;
fill:#30BAE4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 2787 768"preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid;">


<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhgP9.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
 <g id="hat" transform="translate(-1320,-180)" >
  <path d="m1299.3 183.9 46.5-16.7 2.7 6-46.7 16.7zM1308.9 180.6l-10.2-29.1 28.5-9.9 10.4 28.8" />
  <path d="m1308.9 180.6-10.2-29.1 28.5-9.9 10.4 28.8z" />
   </g>
  
    
 <g id="winterHat"  stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"  >
 <path fill="#2FBAE5" d="M938.7 261.2H1063.9V631.7H938.7Z" />
  <path d="M957.4 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M976.1 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M993.2 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1009.4 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1025.5 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1045.1 261.2V631.7" />
  <path d="M1063.9 261.2V631.7" />
  

  <path id="brimHat" fill="#FCB660" d="M938.7 194.3 927.9 194.1c0 0-13.2 0.4-18.7 3.5-3.8 2.2-7.1 5.8-8.7 9.9-1.8 4.4-1 9.4-0.6 14.2 0.4 4.7 1.2 9.5 3 13.9 1.9 4.5 4.8 8.6 7.8 12.3 4 4.9 8.3 9.7 13.6 13.3 6.4 4.3 13.8 6.9 21.1 9.3 6.9 2.3 14.2 3.7 21.4 4.8 6.1 1 12.2 1.2 18.4 1.8 5.9 0.5 11.8 1.4 17.8 1.5 4.9 0.1 9.9-0.2 14.8-0.6 5.6-0.5 11.3-1.1 16.9-2.1 6.7-1.2 13.3-2.6 19.9-4.5 8.3-2.4 16.9-4.3 24.4-8.6 6.4-3.6 12.1-8.5 16.9-14 4.5-5.3 8.4-11.3 10.8-17.8 2-5.4 4-11.5 2.7-17.2-1.3-5.8-5.1-11.3-9.9-14.8-3.6-2.5-12.6-3.3-12.6-3.3l-12.9-0.6z" />
  <path id="brimHat2" fill="#971B59" d="m924.2 194.3c0 0-5.5 6.6-6.6 10.5-0.9 3.3-0.6 6.9 0 10.2 0.8 4.3 2.3 8.6 4.5 12.3 2.2 3.8 5.3 6.9 8.4 9.9 4 3.9 8.4 7.5 13.3 10.2 6.3 3.5 13.2 5.7 20.2 7.5 7 1.9 14.2 2.9 21.4 3.6 5.1 0.6 10.2 0.7 15.4 0.8 5.7 0 11.5-0.4 17.2-0.8 6.5-0.4 13.1-0.7 19.6-1.8 6.3-1.1 12.7-2.3 18.7-4.8 6.5-2.7 12.8-6.2 18.1-10.8 6-5.4 11.9-11.7 14.8-19.3 2.1-5.8 2.9-12.5 1.1-18.4-1.1-3.6-7.1-8.7-7.1-8.7z" /> 
  <path id="topHat" fill="#FCB660" d="m938.7 217.8c0 0-1.2-24.8-1.9-37.1-1.2-21.7-2.3-42.8-3.9-65-0.3-4-2.2-10.5 5.8-10.5 40 0 84.2-2.1 125.6 0.5 4.1 0.3 10.9-0.5 11.8 3.4 0.7 3-0.4 7.8-0.4 7.8l-4.2 53.6-2.9 47.1z" /> 
  <path id="bottomHat" fill="#FEFBFE"  d="m938.7 221.1 129.4 0.1-0.5 16.7c0 0-38.7 5.5-58.2 5.7-22.6 0.2-67.7-5.4-67.7-5.4z" />
  
  </g> 
  
 
            <!-- Анимация шляпы на синих прямоугольниках --> 
  <animateTransform id="an_BigHat" xlink:href="#winterHat" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click;an_BigHat.end+3s" dur="4s" values="0,0;0,250;0,0;0,300;0,250;0,400;0,100;0,500;0,0" repeatCount="1" />  
    <!-- Луна -->
 <g  stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"  transform="rotate(30,1753,10.4)">
  <path id="moon"  fill="#8BECBD" d="m1729 45 28-35 36 31-28 33zM1717 37l58 48-5 8-57-49M1717 37l58 48-5 8-57-49" />
  <path fill="#8BECBD" d="m1717 37 58 48-5 8-57-49z" />
  <path  fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1724 54c0 0-11 15-15 23-4 9-7 19-8 30-1 10 0 21 3 31 2 9 6 18 11 25 5 7 10 13 17 18 8 6 16 11 25 15 11 4 23 6 34 5 9 0 19-3 27-6 5-2 11-4 15-7 6-4 11-8 16-13 2-2 5-7 5-7l-15 3-17 0-20-5-14-7-14-13-10-15-3-6c0 0 3-1 4-1 1-1 2-2 3-3 1-2 1-4 0-6 0-1-2-1-2-2-1-1-3-2-4-4-1-1-2-2-3-4-1-2-2-4-3-6 0-4 2-13 2-13z" />
  <path d="m1746 128c0 0 6 6 9 7 4 1 12 0 12 0" />
  <path d="m1745 96c2 0 4 1 4 2 1 1 1 3 0 4-1 1-2 2-3 2-1 0-3-1-4-2-1-1-1-2 0-4 1-1 2-2 3-2z" /> 
    
        <!-- Анимация луны  an_hat.end-->
  <animateTransform id="an_Moon" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s" values="30,1753,10.4;
                10,1753,10.4;
                20,1753,10.4; 
                -30,1753,10.4;
                0,1753,10.4;
                30,1753,10.4"
                keyTimes="0;0.15;0.25;0.45;0.85;1"
                repeatCount="indefinite" 
              />   
                    
 </g>   
 </svg>
</div>

<script>
let bb = moon.getBBox();
console.log( bb.x + bb.width / 2 ); // координата X  
console.log(bb.y); // координата Y
</script>
```

**#2. Летающие шляпы**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шляпы (растровые изображения) вначале спрятаны за верхним краем холста.
При наступлении определенного времени или других условий, включается команда трансформации перемещения шляп.

```
 <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Carnaval" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Khg.png"  width="206px" height="218px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+3s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-250 800" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image>
```

```css
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 2787 768">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="16" result="shadow"/>
       <feComposite in2="mask" in="shadow" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge> 
    </filter>  
</defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhgP9.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
 <g>
<image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="GimmeSpace" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CE3b.png"  width="206px" height="218px"> 
       <animateTransform id="an_Gimme" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+0.25s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-400 800" fill="freeze" additive="sum" repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>     
     <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Carnaval" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Khg.png"  width="206px" height="218px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+3s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-250 800" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>      
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="ThisIsFine" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFTT7.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+6s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;50 780" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g> 
      <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Kitsune" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q507j.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+8s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;640 390;-150 680" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
    </g>    
    <g>
      <image filter="url(#dropShadow)" id="Samovar" transform="translate(1200,-200)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1O31.png"  width="200px" height="200px"> 
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+10s" dur="3s"  
        values="0 0;-800 400;400 200;-100 780" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1" />  
     </image> 
</g>  
</svg>
</div>
```

**#3. Шагающая шляпа**

- Нужно сначала вырезать контуры шляпы
- дорисовать ноги шляпы в векторном редакторе
- в растровом редакторе заместить место, занимаемое шляпой фоном.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имитацию ходьбы можно реализовать поочередным подниманием левой и правой ноги и одновременным перемещением всей фигуры.

3.1 Поднимание левой ноги,
это по сути вращение вокруг самой верхней точки ноги.
Именно для этого нужно было  прорисовать весь контур ноги, чтобы найти с помощью `getBBox()` координаты точки вращения, как это было сделано в пункте *1 Вращение луны*

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 2787 768">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="16" result="shadow"/>
       <feComposite in2="mask" in="shadow" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge> 
    </filter>  
</defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAr3.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
   
 <g id="LegL" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2">
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1721 765 5-66 46 0-12 28c0 0-1 8 0 12 1 3 3 6 6 8 2 2 5 3 8 3 2 1 4 0 5 1 2 1 3 3 4 5 0 1 0 3-1 4-1 1-2 3-4 3-19 1-58 0-58 0zM1734 698l1-11" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1734 698 1-11v-13l-1-8c0 0-1-20-3-30-1-5-4-16-4-16l33-13 5 10 5 10c0 0 3 10 5 14 1 4 3 7 4 11 0 4-1 11-1 11l-3 13-4 11-4 10z" />
     <!-- Анимация левой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="LeftForward" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.5s" 
      values="0 1731 607;-28 1731 607;0 1731 607" fill="freeze" repeatCount="2" /> 
     
  </g> 
  
   <g id="LegR" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(28 1817 587)">
  <path fill="#FEFAFE" d="m1886 682 38 54c0 0 33-18 48-30 1-1 3-2 3-3 1-1 1-3 0-5-1-2-2-3-4-4-2-1-4 0-6 0-2 0-4 2-5 2-2 0-3 0-5 0-3 0-6 0-9-2-3-2-4-7-6-10-5-8-15-25-15-25zM1915 663" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1915 663c0 0-8-14-13-21-4-5-8-11-13-16-2-2-5-4-8-6-3-3-6-5-9-8-8-6-15-15-24-19-9-3-22-9-29-2-3 3-1 9 0 14 1 5 5 10 8 15 2 3 5 7 8 10 4 4 9 6 13 9 5 4 8 8 13 12 6 5 12 9 18 15 3 3 8 9 8 9l4 7z" />
    
      
  </g>
    <g id="Hand" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"> 
  <path id=HandR fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1861 533c4-1 7 3 11 4 3 1 5 1 8 2 4 1 9 2 13 2 4 0 8 1 12 0 4 0 7-2 11-2 3 0 5-1 8-1 2 0 3-1 5-1 1 0 2-1 3-1 1 0 2 2 3 3 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2-1 3-2 2-5 3-7 4-3 1-7 2-10 3-3 1-6 2-9 3-3 1-6 1-9 1-3 0-6 0-9 0-5 0-11-1-16-2-3-1-6-2-9-4-2-1-4-2-5-3-1-2-2-4-2-7 0-2 2-5 4-5zM1678 585" />
  <path id=HandL fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1678 585c-2 0-5 2-7 3-3 1-6 3-8 5-3 2-5 4-7 7-3 3-5 6-8 10-2 2-3 4-4 6-2 3-2 6-4 9-1 3-2 5-3 8-1 3-1 5-1 8-1 3-2 6-2 9 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 3 1 0 2-2 3-3 1-2 2-5 2-7 1-3 2-6 3-10 2-4 3-8 5-11 2-3 4-5 6-7 2-3 4-6 7-8 2-2 5-3 7-4 2-1 5-2 7-4 2-1 4-2 5-4 1-2 3-5 2-7-1-3-5-5-8-5z" /> 
  

 <path id="BigHat" fill="#FDB761" d="m1628 513c0 0-45-16-69-24-2-1-4-3-4-5 4-13 7-25 12-36 4-9 8-18 13-27 1-2 4-3 6-2 24 8 69 25 69 25 0 0-10 22-14 33-4 12-12 37-12 37zM1622 540l4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12" />
  <path fill="#FDB761" d="m1622 540 4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12c0 0 2-7 5-9 1-1 2 0 3 0 2 0 6 2 6 2l2 1-7 8-8 18-10 24-8 20-7 19c0 0-4 11-5 16-1 5 0 7-1 16 0 3-8-1-8-1z" />

 <path id="AngleHat" fill="#991458" d="m1641 530-8 13c0 0-1-1-2-1-2-4 0-10 1-14 1-5 4-15 4-15z" /> 
 
  <path id="AngleHat2" fill="#991458" d="m1663 442 4-10 2-4 7-8c0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 5 0 5l-1 7-7 4z" />
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1694 664-58-151c0 0 16-46 25-66 6-14 28-16 77-36 61-25 75-26 75-26l81 200c0 0-61 22-91 34-36 15-108 46-108 46z" /> 
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1634.1 695.2 55.2-28.6 94.7-41.3 126.2-45.7 41.6-12.2c0 0 4.7-2.4 6-0.9 3.7 4.7 7.1 11 4.3 12.4-5.3 2.5-20.4 5.7-20.4 5.7l-32 9.6-97.1 36-133.4 56.1c0 0-18.8 8.4-27.5 14-4.2 2.7-8.5 5.7-11.7 9.4-2.7 3.2-6-14.5-6-14.5z" />
  <path fill="#921D57" d="m1962.3 579.8 0.9 3.3-11.1 8.4-30.1 13.6-31.6 13.9-52.4 22-56.6 22.9-50.9 19.9-25.9 8.7-27.4 9.3-20.5 6.9c0 0-12.3 5.8-17.2 2.7-4.6-3 12.3-10.8 12.3-10.8l23.2-11.7 59.6-24.7 44.3-18.7 55.7-23.8 37.9-12.3 34.6-12.9 26.5-8.7 18.1-4.5 6.6-1.8z" />  
      
  </g>   
     
       
  </svg>
    </div>
```

3.2 Поднимание правой ноги

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 2787 768">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="16" result="shadow"/>
       <feComposite in2="mask" in="shadow" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge> 
    </filter>  
</defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAr3.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
  
 <g id="LegL" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2">
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1721 765 5-66 46 0-12 28c0 0-1 8 0 12 1 3 3 6 6 8 2 2 5 3 8 3 2 1 4 0 5 1 2 1 3 3 4 5 0 1 0 3-1 4-1 1-2 3-4 3-19 1-58 0-58 0zM1734 698l1-11" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1734 698 1-11v-13l-1-8c0 0-1-20-3-30-1-5-4-16-4-16l33-13 5 10 5 10c0 0 3 10 5 14 1 4 3 7 4 11 0 4-1 11-1 11l-3 13-4 11-4 10z" />
   
     
  </g> 
  
   <g id="LegR" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(28 1817 587)">
  <path fill="#FEFAFE" d="m1886 682 38 54c0 0 33-18 48-30 1-1 3-2 3-3 1-1 1-3 0-5-1-2-2-3-4-4-2-1-4 0-6 0-2 0-4 2-5 2-2 0-3 0-5 0-3 0-6 0-9-2-3-2-4-7-6-10-5-8-15-25-15-25zM1915 663" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1915 663c0 0-8-14-13-21-4-5-8-11-13-16-2-2-5-4-8-6-3-3-6-5-9-8-8-6-15-15-24-19-9-3-22-9-29-2-3 3-1 9 0 14 1 5 5 10 8 15 2 3 5 7 8 10 4 4 9 6 13 9 5 4 8 8 13 12 6 5 12 9 18 15 3 3 8 9 8 9l4 7z" />
     <!-- Анимация правой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="RightBack" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="0.5s" 
      values="28 1817 587;0 1817 587;28 1817 587"  repeatCount="2" fill="freeze" /> 
      
  </g>
    <g id="Hand" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"> 
  <path id=HandR fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1861 533c4-1 7 3 11 4 3 1 5 1 8 2 4 1 9 2 13 2 4 0 8 1 12 0 4 0 7-2 11-2 3 0 5-1 8-1 2 0 3-1 5-1 1 0 2-1 3-1 1 0 2 2 3 3 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2-1 3-2 2-5 3-7 4-3 1-7 2-10 3-3 1-6 2-9 3-3 1-6 1-9 1-3 0-6 0-9 0-5 0-11-1-16-2-3-1-6-2-9-4-2-1-4-2-5-3-1-2-2-4-2-7 0-2 2-5 4-5zM1678 585" />
  <path id=HandL fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1678 585c-2 0-5 2-7 3-3 1-6 3-8 5-3 2-5 4-7 7-3 3-5 6-8 10-2 2-3 4-4 6-2 3-2 6-4 9-1 3-2 5-3 8-1 3-1 5-1 8-1 3-2 6-2 9 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 3 1 0 2-2 3-3 1-2 2-5 2-7 1-3 2-6 3-10 2-4 3-8 5-11 2-3 4-5 6-7 2-3 4-6 7-8 2-2 5-3 7-4 2-1 5-2 7-4 2-1 4-2 5-4 1-2 3-5 2-7-1-3-5-5-8-5z" /> 
  

 <path id="BigHat" fill="#FDB761" d="m1628 513c0 0-45-16-69-24-2-1-4-3-4-5 4-13 7-25 12-36 4-9 8-18 13-27 1-2 4-3 6-2 24 8 69 25 69 25 0 0-10 22-14 33-4 12-12 37-12 37zM1622 540l4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12" />
  <path fill="#FDB761" d="m1622 540 4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12c0 0 2-7 5-9 1-1 2 0 3 0 2 0 6 2 6 2l2 1-7 8-8 18-10 24-8 20-7 19c0 0-4 11-5 16-1 5 0 7-1 16 0 3-8-1-8-1z" />

 <path id="AngleHat" fill="#991458" d="m1641 530-8 13c0 0-1-1-2-1-2-4 0-10 1-14 1-5 4-15 4-15z" /> 
 
  <path id="AngleHat2" fill="#991458" d="m1663 442 4-10 2-4 7-8c0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 5 0 5l-1 7-7 4z" />
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1694 664-58-151c0 0 16-46 25-66 6-14 28-16 77-36 61-25 75-26 75-26l81 200c0 0-61 22-91 34-36 15-108 46-108 46z" /> 
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1634.1 695.2 55.2-28.6 94.7-41.3 126.2-45.7 41.6-12.2c0 0 4.7-2.4 6-0.9 3.7 4.7 7.1 11 4.3 12.4-5.3 2.5-20.4 5.7-20.4 5.7l-32 9.6-97.1 36-133.4 56.1c0 0-18.8 8.4-27.5 14-4.2 2.7-8.5 5.7-11.7 9.4-2.7 3.2-6-14.5-6-14.5z" />
  <path fill="#921D57" d="m1962.3 579.8 0.9 3.3-11.1 8.4-30.1 13.6-31.6 13.9-52.4 22-56.6 22.9-50.9 19.9-25.9 8.7-27.4 9.3-20.5 6.9c0 0-12.3 5.8-17.2 2.7-4.6-3 12.3-10.8 12.3-10.8l23.2-11.7 59.6-24.7 44.3-18.7 55.7-23.8 37.9-12.3 34.6-12.9 26.5-8.7 18.1-4.5 6.6-1.8z" />  
      
  </g>   
       
  </svg>
    </div>
```

3.3 Чередование поднимания ног

Реализуется с помощью логических цепочек, которые можно выразить словами:

анимация правой ноги (1 раз) -> анимация подъема левой ноги (1 раз) -> анимация правой ноги (1 раз) и так зациклить

`begin="svg1.click"` -> `begin="RightBack.end"` -> `begin="svg1.click;LeftForward.end"`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 2787 768">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="16" result="shadow"/>
       <feComposite in2="mask" in="shadow" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge> 
    </filter>  
</defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAr3.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
   
 <g id="LegL" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2">
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1721 765 5-66 46 0-12 28c0 0-1 8 0 12 1 3 3 6 6 8 2 2 5 3 8 3 2 1 4 0 5 1 2 1 3 3 4 5 0 1 0 3-1 4-1 1-2 3-4 3-19 1-58 0-58 0zM1734 698l1-11" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1734 698 1-11v-13l-1-8c0 0-1-20-3-30-1-5-4-16-4-16l33-13 5 10 5 10c0 0 3 10 5 14 1 4 3 7 4 11 0 4-1 11-1 11l-3 13-4 11-4 10z" />
     <!-- Анимация левой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="LeftForward" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="RightBack.end" dur="0.5s" 
      values="0 1731 607;-28 1731 607;0 1731 607" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
     
  </g> 
  
   <g id="LegR" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(28 1817 587)">
  <path fill="#FEFAFE" d="m1886 682 38 54c0 0 33-18 48-30 1-1 3-2 3-3 1-1 1-3 0-5-1-2-2-3-4-4-2-1-4 0-6 0-2 0-4 2-5 2-2 0-3 0-5 0-3 0-6 0-9-2-3-2-4-7-6-10-5-8-15-25-15-25zM1915 663" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1915 663c0 0-8-14-13-21-4-5-8-11-13-16-2-2-5-4-8-6-3-3-6-5-9-8-8-6-15-15-24-19-9-3-22-9-29-2-3 3-1 9 0 14 1 5 5 10 8 15 2 3 5 7 8 10 4 4 9 6 13 9 5 4 8 8 13 12 6 5 12 9 18 15 3 3 8 9 8 9l4 7z" />
     <!-- Анимация правой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="RightBack" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click;LeftForward.end" dur="0.5s" 
      values="28 1817 587;0 1817 587;28 1817 587" fill="freeze" /> 
      
  </g>
    <g id="Hand" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"> 
  <path id=HandR fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1861 533c4-1 7 3 11 4 3 1 5 1 8 2 4 1 9 2 13 2 4 0 8 1 12 0 4 0 7-2 11-2 3 0 5-1 8-1 2 0 3-1 5-1 1 0 2-1 3-1 1 0 2 2 3 3 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2-1 3-2 2-5 3-7 4-3 1-7 2-10 3-3 1-6 2-9 3-3 1-6 1-9 1-3 0-6 0-9 0-5 0-11-1-16-2-3-1-6-2-9-4-2-1-4-2-5-3-1-2-2-4-2-7 0-2 2-5 4-5zM1678 585" />
  <path id=HandL fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1678 585c-2 0-5 2-7 3-3 1-6 3-8 5-3 2-5 4-7 7-3 3-5 6-8 10-2 2-3 4-4 6-2 3-2 6-4 9-1 3-2 5-3 8-1 3-1 5-1 8-1 3-2 6-2 9 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 3 1 0 2-2 3-3 1-2 2-5 2-7 1-3 2-6 3-10 2-4 3-8 5-11 2-3 4-5 6-7 2-3 4-6 7-8 2-2 5-3 7-4 2-1 5-2 7-4 2-1 4-2 5-4 1-2 3-5 2-7-1-3-5-5-8-5z" /> 
  

 <path id="BigHat" fill="#FDB761" d="m1628 513c0 0-45-16-69-24-2-1-4-3-4-5 4-13 7-25 12-36 4-9 8-18 13-27 1-2 4-3 6-2 24 8 69 25 69 25 0 0-10 22-14 33-4 12-12 37-12 37zM1622 540l4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12" />
  <path fill="#FDB761" d="m1622 540 4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12c0 0 2-7 5-9 1-1 2 0 3 0 2 0 6 2 6 2l2 1-7 8-8 18-10 24-8 20-7 19c0 0-4 11-5 16-1 5 0 7-1 16 0 3-8-1-8-1z" />

 <path id="AngleHat" fill="#991458" d="m1641 530-8 13c0 0-1-1-2-1-2-4 0-10 1-14 1-5 4-15 4-15z" /> 
 
  <path id="AngleHat2" fill="#991458" d="m1663 442 4-10 2-4 7-8c0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 5 0 5l-1 7-7 4z" />
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1694 664-58-151c0 0 16-46 25-66 6-14 28-16 77-36 61-25 75-26 75-26l81 200c0 0-61 22-91 34-36 15-108 46-108 46z" /> 
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1634.1 695.2 55.2-28.6 94.7-41.3 126.2-45.7 41.6-12.2c0 0 4.7-2.4 6-0.9 3.7 4.7 7.1 11 4.3 12.4-5.3 2.5-20.4 5.7-20.4 5.7l-32 9.6-97.1 36-133.4 56.1c0 0-18.8 8.4-27.5 14-4.2 2.7-8.5 5.7-11.7 9.4-2.7 3.2-6-14.5-6-14.5z" />
  <path fill="#921D57" d="m1962.3 579.8 0.9 3.3-11.1 8.4-30.1 13.6-31.6 13.9-52.4 22-56.6 22.9-50.9 19.9-25.9 8.7-27.4 9.3-20.5 6.9c0 0-12.3 5.8-17.2 2.7-4.6-3 12.3-10.8 12.3-10.8l23.2-11.7 59.6-24.7 44.3-18.7 55.7-23.8 37.9-12.3 34.6-12.9 26.5-8.7 18.1-4.5 6.6-1.8z" />  
      
  </g>   
      
  </svg>
    </div>
```

3.4 Добавляем к анимации ног перемещение шляпы в пространстве

```
 <!-- Анимация горизонтального движения шляпы -->
       <animateTransform id="an_Horiz" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="an_hat.end+5s;an_Horiz.end+2s" dur="20s"   
        values="0, 0;600 0;600,-350;0,0" fill="freeze" additive="sum" repeatCount="1" />   
<g>
```

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 2787 768">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dropShadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="4" stdDeviation="16" result="shadow"/>
       <feComposite in2="mask" in="shadow" operator="in" result="comp" />
      <feMerge result="merge">
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        <feMergeNode in="comp" />
      </feMerge> 
    </filter>  
</defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAr3.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
<g id="Hat+Legs" >   
 <g id="LegL" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2">
  <path fill="#FFFBFF" d="m1721 765 5-66 46 0-12 28c0 0-1 8 0 12 1 3 3 6 6 8 2 2 5 3 8 3 2 1 4 0 5 1 2 1 3 3 4 5 0 1 0 3-1 4-1 1-2 3-4 3-19 1-58 0-58 0zM1734 698l1-11" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1734 698 1-11v-13l-1-8c0 0-1-20-3-30-1-5-4-16-4-16l33-13 5 10 5 10c0 0 3 10 5 14 1 4 3 7 4 11 0 4-1 11-1 11l-3 13-4 11-4 10z" />
     <!-- Анимация левой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="LeftForward" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="RightBack.end" dur="0.5s" 
      values="0 1731 607;-28 1731 607;0 1731 607" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
     
  </g> 
  
   <g id="LegR" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2" transform="rotate(28 1817 587)">
  <path fill="#FEFAFE" d="m1886 682 38 54c0 0 33-18 48-30 1-1 3-2 3-3 1-1 1-3 0-5-1-2-2-3-4-4-2-1-4 0-6 0-2 0-4 2-5 2-2 0-3 0-5 0-3 0-6 0-9-2-3-2-4-7-6-10-5-8-15-25-15-25zM1915 663" />
  <path fill="#8DEBBC" d="m1915 663c0 0-8-14-13-21-4-5-8-11-13-16-2-2-5-4-8-6-3-3-6-5-9-8-8-6-15-15-24-19-9-3-22-9-29-2-3 3-1 9 0 14 1 5 5 10 8 15 2 3 5 7 8 10 4 4 9 6 13 9 5 4 8 8 13 12 6 5 12 9 18 15 3 3 8 9 8 9l4 7z" />
     <!-- Анимация правой ноги -->
   <animateTransform id="RightBack" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click;LeftForward.end" dur="0.5s" 
      values="28 1817 587;0 1817 587;28 1817 587" fill="freeze" /> 
      
  </g>
    <g id="Hand" stroke="#971B59" stroke-width="2"> 
  <path id=HandR fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1861 533c4-1 7 3 11 4 3 1 5 1 8 2 4 1 9 2 13 2 4 0 8 1 12 0 4 0 7-2 11-2 3 0 5-1 8-1 2 0 3-1 5-1 1 0 2-1 3-1 1 0 2 2 3 3 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2-1 3-2 2-5 3-7 4-3 1-7 2-10 3-3 1-6 2-9 3-3 1-6 1-9 1-3 0-6 0-9 0-5 0-11-1-16-2-3-1-6-2-9-4-2-1-4-2-5-3-1-2-2-4-2-7 0-2 2-5 4-5zM1678 585" />
  <path id=HandL fill="#8AEEB4" d="m1678 585c-2 0-5 2-7 3-3 1-6 3-8 5-3 2-5 4-7 7-3 3-5 6-8 10-2 2-3 4-4 6-2 3-2 6-4 9-1 3-2 5-3 8-1 3-1 5-1 8-1 3-2 6-2 9 0 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 2 3 4 3 1 0 2-2 3-3 1-2 2-5 2-7 1-3 2-6 3-10 2-4 3-8 5-11 2-3 4-5 6-7 2-3 4-6 7-8 2-2 5-3 7-4 2-1 5-2 7-4 2-1 4-2 5-4 1-2 3-5 2-7-1-3-5-5-8-5z" /> 
  

 <path id="BigHat" fill="#FDB761" d="m1628 513c0 0-45-16-69-24-2-1-4-3-4-5 4-13 7-25 12-36 4-9 8-18 13-27 1-2 4-3 6-2 24 8 69 25 69 25 0 0-10 22-14 33-4 12-12 37-12 37zM1622 540l4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12" />
  <path fill="#FDB761" d="m1622 540 4-20 9-27 9-26 11-27 5-12c0 0 2-7 5-9 1-1 2 0 3 0 2 0 6 2 6 2l2 1-7 8-8 18-10 24-8 20-7 19c0 0-4 11-5 16-1 5 0 7-1 16 0 3-8-1-8-1z" />

 <path id="AngleHat" fill="#991458" d="m1641 530-8 13c0 0-1-1-2-1-2-4 0-10 1-14 1-5 4-15 4-15z" /> 
 
  <path id="AngleHat2" fill="#991458" d="m1663 442 4-10 2-4 7-8c0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 5 0 5l-1 7-7 4z" />
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1694 664-58-151c0 0 16-46 25-66 6-14 28-16 77-36 61-25 75-26 75-26l81 200c0 0-61 22-91 34-36 15-108 46-108 46z" /> 
  
  <path fill="#30BBE4" d="m1634.1 695.2 55.2-28.6 94.7-41.3 126.2-45.7 41.6-12.2c0 0 4.7-2.4 6-0.9 3.7 4.7 7.1 11 4.3 12.4-5.3 2.5-20.4 5.7-20.4 5.7l-32 9.6-97.1 36-133.4 56.1c0 0-18.8 8.4-27.5 14-4.2 2.7-8.5 5.7-11.7 9.4-2.7 3.2-6-14.5-6-14.5z" />
  <path fill="#921D57" d="m1962.3 579.8 0.9 3.3-11.1 8.4-30.1 13.6-31.6 13.9-52.4 22-56.6 22.9-50.9 19.9-25.9 8.7-27.4 9.3-20.5 6.9c0 0-12.3 5.8-17.2 2.7-4.6-3 12.3-10.8 12.3-10.8l23.2-11.7 59.6-24.7 44.3-18.7 55.7-23.8 37.9-12.3 34.6-12.9 26.5-8.7 18.1-4.5 6.6-1.8z" />  
      
  </g>   
        <!-- Анимация горизонтального движения шляпы -->
       <animateTransform id="an_Horiz" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+3s;an_Horiz.end+2s" dur="20s"   
        values="0, 0;600 0;600,-350;0,0" fill="freeze" additive="sum" repeatCount="1" />   
        <g>
     <!-- глаза + рот большой шляпы eyes + mouth of a big hat -->
  <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="m1831.7 535.5c0 0 10.1 14.4 16.8 9.9 5.9-4 4.4-17.1 4.4-17.1" />
  <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.1 509.1c1.1-0.6 2.6 0.1 3.5 0.9 1.7 1.5 2.5 3.9 2.6 6.1 0.1 1.3 0.1 3.1-1.1 3.7-1.2 0.7-3.1-0.3-4-1.3-1.6-1.6-1.9-4.2-1.9-6.4 0-1.1-0.1-2.6 0.9-3.1zM1824.7 510.4" />
  <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.7 510.4c0.5-0.3 1.2 0.3 1.7 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.9 1.1 1.2 1.7 0.4 0.8 0.7 1.6 1 2.5 0.1 0.5 0.3 1 0.2 1.5-0.1 0.7 0 1.7-0.6 2-0.7 0.3-1.5-0.4-2-0.9-0.6-0.6-0.8-1.4-1.1-2.2-0.4-1.1-0.6-2.3-0.7-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.5 0.2-1.8z" />
  <g transform="translate(18.821694,-6.6252361)">
    <path  stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.1 509.1c1.1-0.6 2.6 0.1 3.5 0.9 1.7 1.5 2.5 3.9 2.6 6.1 0.1 1.3 0.1 3.1-1.1 3.7-1.2 0.7-3.1-0.3-4-1.3-1.6-1.6-1.9-4.2-1.9-6.4 0-1.1-0.1-2.6 0.9-3.1zM1824.7 510.4" />
    <path stroke="#725598" stroke-width="4" d="m1824.7 510.4c0.5-0.3 1.2 0.3 1.7 0.7 0.6 0.4 0.9 1.1 1.2 1.7 0.4 0.8 0.7 1.6 1 2.5 0.1 0.5 0.3 1 0.2 1.5-0.1 0.7 0 1.7-0.6 2-0.7 0.3-1.5-0.4-2-0.9-0.6-0.6-0.8-1.4-1.1-2.2-0.4-1.1-0.6-2.3-0.7-3.5 0-0.6-0.3-1.5 0.2-1.8z" />
   <!--  Анимация глаз + рта вверх-вниз -->
   </g>  
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click+3s" dur="1s"  
        values="0 0;0 -20;-5 -20;0 0" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="indefinite" />  
    </g>
    </g>   
     
  </svg>
    </div>
```