# Как вставить тег audio в path?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, svg-path

Есть такой код

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 998.66669 632">
    <path data-text="222" data-photo="/pubs/share/direct/508202351.jpg" data-title="111" class="interactive__point" d="m 296.1451,111.72287 21.67973,-21.390665 22.40239,22.113325 -22.11333,22.11332 z"/>
</svg>
```

в него нужно добавить

```html
<audio controls="controls" height="43" preload="none" src="/508202559.wav" width="400">&nbsp;</audio>
```

Подскажите, каким образом можно audio вставить в path. Cпасибо !

Comment: Тег audio нельзя вставить в path. Объясните лучше зачем вам это понадобилось? Какого эффекта вы ожидаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В тег `<path>` кроме координат,   команд для кривых и стилей представления больше ничего невозможно добавить.
Наверное вы хотели, чтобы фигура svg была управляющим элементом для `<audio>`

```js
var zodiac = new Audio();
zodiac.src = src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Kendi Dalfer–Meeting.mp3";

function play() {
  zodiac.play();
}
```

```html
 <svg viewbox="0 0 998.66669 632">
   <g id="btn1"  onclick='play()' >
   <text x="296" y="90" font-size="48px" >Play </text>
    <path data-text="222" data-photo="/pubs/share/direct/508202351.jpg" data-title="111" class="interactive__point" d="m 296.1451,111.72287 21.67973,-21.390665 22.40239,22.113325 -22.11333,22.11332 z"/>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: за далфер плюс ...

Comment: @Айболит Спасибо Максим [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226511/28748) уже использовал этот трек. Там анимацию старался подогнать под акценты в музыке

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо за участие в решении проблемы !
Ввёл доп. data-атрибут с src аудио, а вывел сам плеер через js.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]