# Одинаковая анимация работает по-разному

Tags: css-animation, transform

Есть сайт, создан скорее для тренировки.
https://seregasmyfavoritesites.on.drv.tw/Site/Kvashenaya/
Рабочий на 99%. На нем есть 2 анимации.
Два heading "КВАШЕНАЯ" и "САША".
К ним приклеены 2 анимации, практически одинаковые.

```
<style>
 :root {
 --visota: 100vh;
 --visota_menu: calc(20px + 7vw);
 **--visota_real**: calc(var(--visota) - var(--visota_menu) );
 --random }
 </style>

<style>
@keyframes a_Down_Random {
  from {transform-origin: center top}
  75%  {transform-origin: center bottom;
        transform: perspective(500px)
                   translate3d(400px, var(--visota_real), 0px)
                   rotateX(calc(var(--random,1)*360deg)) 
                   rotateY(calc(var(--random,1)*360deg))
                   rotateZ(calc(var(--random,1)*180deg)) } }
                   
@keyframes a_X0to60-Zminus60plus30 {                
        from {transform-origin: left top}               
          5% {transform: rotateX(-10deg)}
          9% {transform: rotateX(15deg)}
         13% {transform: rotateX(-40deg)}
         17% {transform: rotateX(60deg)}
         21% {transform: rotateX(-60deg)}
         25% {transform: rotateX(40deg)}
         29% {transform: rotateX(-30deg)}
         33% {transform: rotateX(20deg)}
         37% {transform: rotateX(-10deg)}
         41% {transform: rotateX(5deg)}
         45% {transform: rotateX(0deg)}
         49% {transform: rotateZ(70deg)}
         53% {transform: rotateZ(15deg)}
         57% {transform: rotateZ(60deg)}
         61% {transform: rotateZ(20deg)}
         65% {transform: rotateZ(50deg)}
         69% {transform: rotateZ(30deg)}
         73% {transform: rotateZ(35deg)}
         85% {transform: rotateX(85deg)
                         rotateZ(20deg) 
                         translateY(var(--visota_real)) }
          to {transform-origin: left top}  }
</style>
```

Ответ: в точке 85% строку rotateX(85deg) перенести после translateY()

Слово "КВАШЕНАЯ" падает по анимации **a_Down_Random {}**,
Слово "САША" падает по анимации **a_X0to60-Zminus60plus30 {}**,

остальной код, наверное, лишний. Т.к. все отображается приблизительно правильно, анимация запускается.

Слово "КВАШЕНАЯ" падает верно. Слово "САША" падает ПОЧТИ верно . Оно болтается до своих 73% правильно. Но далее в строке
**85% {transform: translateY(var(--visota_real))**
что-то ломается. Эта "САША" движется вниз на **неизвестную** (может, половина высоты экрана ?) высоту (а должна на точно такую же высоту , как и слово "КВАШЕНАЯ") и возвращается вверх. Почему ?

Эти анимации одинаковые. Используют одну CSS-переменную **var(--visota_real)**  -- она примерно показывает высоту экрана.
По задумке эта "САША" должна опуститься на высоту **translateY(var(--visota_real))** , и за 15% времени подняться в исходную позицию.
Почему ее сносит вниз и сразу назад вверх ? Почему ее тянет в ноль экрана ?
Я подозреваю, что это связано со **transform-origin:** . Где-то на этих 85% происходит то, что центр этой "САШИ" определяется не внутри нее, а наверху страницы, где она висит изначально.
Не могу понять -- там же все одинаковое !

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `transform-origin`

Comment: @DiMithras, так а куда мне его записать . Я всю жизнь думал, что  transform-origin относится к самому объекту, а не к родителю. Там и так уже 2 штуки указано.  В короткой анимации нет даже to {}, и все работает.

Comment: @DiMithras, Короткая анимация падает ровно на высоту var(--visota_real) , как и записано. Почему длинная анимация не может  упасть на ту же высоту ?

Comment: @DiMithras, я утверждал, что все одинаково. Но нет.  Для чистоты я вставил transform:perspective(500px) -- и что то изменилось ! Эту САШУ стало болтать по всему экрану. А какая связь  translate  и  perspective(500px) ?

Answer (score 1):

Я понял, простое очевидное решение. **transform-origin** не причем.
В короткой анимации важна последовательность : сначала  **translateY** и **translateX**, а потом уже **rotateX** или **rotateY**. **rotateX** и **Y**  поворачивает ось объекта. И после   **rotateX** все перемещения происходят в новой плоскости. При изменении **translateX** и **translateY** и **rotateZ**
ось объекта не изменяется, она и так смотрит на экран.
Все повороты после перемещений.
Скорее всего, здесь надо указать еще
**transform-style: preserve-3d** (хотя для лучшего дизайну, здесь лучше указать **flat**)

@DiMithras,  спасибо за попытку ! :)

Comment: Вам спасибо, что в ответ оформили :)

Comment: Ещё можете поэкспериментировать с `transform-style: preserve-3d`

Comment: @DiMithras,  исправлять сам вопрос? Тут все равно код недостаточен для проверки. Там надо библиотеки 2 штуки подключать на   onmouseenter() и HTML писать. Много работы :)

Comment: Да нет, если удовлетворены результатам, ничего не надо менять, а по нюансам можно новый вопрос сделать. И постараться в [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), просто даже хотя бы ради того, чтобы вопрос-ответ были полезны остальным участникам или случайно заглянувшим.

Comment: Мне сайт выдал целый 1 балл за решение собственного вопроса :). Это неверно. Так рейтинг превратится в фантик

Comment: Отвечать на свои вопросы даже несколько раз и получать за это баллы вполне [нормальная практика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226510/Анимация-лого-winter-bash). Можно даже переводить вопросы-ответы с английского SO, если они в формате wiki приносят пользу.

Comment: @DiMithras, в этом вопросе решение найдено.   А если продолжить ? А как двигать уже повернутый объект ? просто в плоскости экрана ? какие есть свойства CSS ?

Comment: `rotate`, `translate`, `scale`. Думаю ничего нового для вас. Это если ограничиться исключительно CSS. А так есть хренова туча js библиотек, в том числе на WebGL.

Comment: Так уже доказали, при 3D-повороте , поворачивается плоскость. Вообще мьранна ситуация. Анимация слева падает , вращается во всех плоскостях. Но падает она по Y строго вниз. А анимация справа при повороте по Х меняет плоскость и translateY может загнать объект за зрителя , за спину ему (поэтому и пропадала с экрана). Я уже сам перестал понимать , как это работает.

Comment: Возможно , есть разница в этом CSS — translate3d(x, y, z)   и тоже самое , но отдельно. 1 выполняется в той плоскости , которая была перед командой . А во 2 случае ось пересчитывается после каждой команды . Вполне. Никогда не обращал на это внимания. Требует проверки